# How to select from the Windows 10 IME suggestion list

Tags: windows-10, input-languages, ime

How do i select item 4 from this list?

It's the standard Windows 10 IME. I found lots of keyboard shortcuts for switching between hiragana, katakana etc but not how to select from the list. Simply pressing 4 enters 4 in the chat box instead of 大好きだ.　Clicking it with the mouse doesn't work either.

[image]

Comment: Is this from a game? If so, what game? Also, did you try arrow keys and enter?

Comment: @LPChip Yes, *but* it is the standard Windows 10 IME for Japanese. It is not a game menu. Arrows don't work, neither do number keys.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is `TAB`. Don't know how i missed this...